# ArrayList of Object with generics type

Tags: java

I have some issues with my generics class. Here the exemple of code:

```
     public abstract class Foo <C extends Component> {
        //some code
     }

     public class Bar extends Foo <ConcretComponent> {
        //some code
     }

    public class Application {
        private ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        public static main (String[] args) {
            fooList.add(new Bar());
        }
    }
```

If I write my code Like this I have a warning at the declaration of fooList because I dont give the genric type of Foo, and the code work correctly. But if I write

```
    private ArrayList<Foo<Component>> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo<Component>>();
```

It give me error at the add because it considère that it is not applicable for a Bar object.
Did I just put a @SupressWarnings or their is a "clean" way to do this?

Comment: private ArrayList<Foo<? extends Component>> fooList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: A note regarding the duplicate: that question uses `ArrayList` where your question uses `Foo`. Your question happens to *also* use `ArrayList`, but that's not actually relevant to your question. (You forgot to make a minimal complete verifiable example.) So don't get confused when comparing your question to the dupe.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I just found how to do it.
I need to use <?> instead of <Component> :
        private ArrayList<Foo<?>> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo<?>>();